# blender deleting folders

Tags: blend-files

I've noticed that when I stop/start blender all of my folders that are subfolders (of the following list) are getting wiped out, including contents I didn't want to lose.   Do these folders need to be exclusively assigned to blender?  Folders in Preferences:

- Temporary Files
- Render Output
- Render Cache

Comment: Please define "some of my (temporary) folders are getting wiped out, including contents I didn't want to lose." What are you talking about?

Comment: Storing "stuff you don't want to loose" in "temporary folders" is arguably a bad practice in itself

Comment: Duarte Farrajota Ramos I also had "daily temporary" log files from other application being stored in these folders.   This is not a bad practice, it is best practice of an Stanford IT professional of 35 years, now retired.  But, no need for soap box lectures to answer specific questions.   It was also odd that blender is also deleting previously rendered frames from other blend files when I shut down an instance.